# $_POST returns empty even when `name` is declared and correct

Tags: php

I have a basic login form in PHP. All the input names are correct, and the types are also properly declared. But a `$_POST` returns empty for whatever unknown reason it may have.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
    <span id="status"></span>
        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="userName">Username</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></span>
                            <input type="text" name="username" required class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Username">
                        </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="passWord">Password</label>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-lock"></span></span>
                            <input type="password" name="password" required class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Password">
                        </div>
        </div>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">
    <button type="reset" value="reset" class="btn btn-danger btn-block">Clear</button>
</form>
```

**Main Script**

```
$username = sanitizeString($_POST["username"]);
$password = sanitizeString($_POST["password"]);
```

The `sanitizeString` function simply removes illegalchars.

Please help me as I have been in this for some hours now. Thanks

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, rather post the actual code here. Also, would be nice to see the entire form, not just pieces of it.

Comment: And can we see the form declaration ?

Comment: Which exact error are you facing? Also, if you do `print_r($_POST);`, does it contain all fields you submitted?

Comment: Oh my. I realized that I have a `$password` set to `""` in my `tempconfig.php`. Thanks for all the comment

Answer (score 0):

Try to add all `input`,  `id` parameter, for example:

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" required class="form-control col-xs-12" placeholder="Username">
```

UPDATE:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>">
```

Replace `<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>` by path, ex: `myphp.php`

Comment: that would make no difference as the ``name="x"`` is used for php'S ``$_POST``